# Trim() and replace() not working in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I successfully created a bookmarklet that takes the current text selection and uses that in a Google search, which is opened in a new browser window:

> javascript:(function(){query=getSelection();window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURI(query));})()

This bookmarklet is working fine. Here the current text selection is placed in the variable "query".

I then tried to make a small amendment, to try to use trim() to strip off any leading or trailing white space in the text selection. So I changed the bookmarklet to:

> javascript:(function(){query=getSelection().trim();window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURI(query));})()

However, with this amendment, the bookmarklet no longer works — when you click on this bookmarklet in the bookmarks bar, nothing happens.

I have also tried to use the regex .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'') to trim the white space, but this also causes the bookmarklet to stop working.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: getSelection() doesn't return a String object.

Comment: You could try to convert the getSelection() to a string, query = getSelection().toString().trim()

Answer (score 1):

[`Window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object, not a `String` object. You can get the `String` object by calling `toString()`:

```
query = getSelection().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try used below code for trim.
due to trim is the JQuery function.
So I hope below code work fine.

```
javascript:(function(){query=$.trim(getSelection());window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURI(query));})()
```

Comment: query = jQuery.trim(getSelection()); OR query = $.trim(getSelection());

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your responses, which identified the problem.

As suggested, it seems the issue was that the selection object needed to be converted to a string object, by calling .toString() or similar approaches, before .trim() is applied.

So the working bookmarklet is now:

> javascript:(function(){query=getSelection().toString().trim();window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURI(query));})()